# Why does collection->where() return index number?

Tags: laravel-5, collections

I'm sure this may be a simple solution, but I can't seem to work it out.

I am trying to use Laravel's `where()` clause to build an array of `$courses` that belong to each `$student`. I cycle through each `$student` and filter the `$courseRecords` to find matching courses based on their StudentCode.

Here is my sample code snippet:

```
// Cycle through the students and add their relevant course details
foreach( $students as $student ) {

    // Find matching courses to the student
    $courses = $courseRecords->where( 'StudentId', $student->StudentCode );

    // Add the course array to the student record
    $student->Courses = $courses;

}
```

However, the result I get, gives me each student's course, but with a leading index number (as shown below in random results):

[image]

I can't seem to work out why this is happening. The first entry (Id 0) is the result I am expecting, but for some reason, every other result seems to give me the matching index number of `$courseRecord`.

I have tried using `$courses->all();` and `$courses->toArray();` but this doesn't make any difference.  From the Laravel documentation (that I have read), it doesn't mention this behaviour which makes me think I have something incorrect.

`$students` and `$courseRecords` are both a collection.

Comment: umm, is this you are trying to retrieve all course for the students? if yes.. why not using the eloquent relations? could you share the result array instead of screenshot? also `$courseRecords->where( 'StudentId', $student->StudentCode );` without `->get()` will return query builder instance, take caution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `values()`:

```php
$courses = $courseRecords->where('StudentId', $student->StudentCode)->values();
```